# Insert Calculated Field into Access Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to insert a record into an Access table that currently has no records.

I have used the below VBA code fine, which works with no issues

```
strDl3 = "INSERT INTO TempTable1 (ID, Name, Customer) VALUES (1,123,5)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDl3
```

However when I try to insert a 4th Calculated Field by using the below it doesn't work

```
strDl4 = "INSERT INTO TempTable1 (ID, Name, Customer, Index) VALUES (2,123,5,[ID] & [Name] & [Customer])"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDl4
```

I get the below error saying

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concatenate like this - and be careful using reserved words:

```
strDl4 = "INSERT INTO TempTable1 (ID, [Name], Customer, [Index]) VALUES (2,123,5,'" & [ID] & [Name] & [Customer] & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. It doesn't seem to be working as is giving an 'External name not defined' error. on the [ID] field after the ' " above. Similarly, if I change the name of the field from ID to TestX both in the Table and the VBA it still doesn't work. Does it make a difference that I am trying to run from a Public Function in VBA?

Comment: Actually just tried it again and it works now. Thank you